# angular2 use component of nested imported module

Tags: angular, typescript

is it possible to have the following strucure?

app.component.js

```
@Component({
    template: '<nav-context></nav-context>'
class AppComponent
```

app.module.js

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CoreModule]
    boostrap: [AppComponent]
```

core.module.js

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [NavModule]
class CoreModule
```

nav.module.js

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [NavContextComponent]
    exports: [NavContextComponent]
class NavModule
```

nav-context.component.js

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-context'
class NavContextComponent
```

So far I get `'nav-context' is not a known element`

Comment: Can you please structure the code in a more organized way? one code section per class

Comment: I restructured my code :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to also export the module if you want it to be provided to importers

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [NavModule]
    exports: [NavModule]
```